# Is there any effect of the length sub-specifier “l“ in the context of the (good) old printf?

Tags: c, printf

The question is about the (good) old printf function.
The length sub-specifier "l" is documented in the table named "specifiers" in:

https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

The cell for the explenation for the combination of the length sub-specifier “l“ with the specifiers "f F e E g G a A" is left blanck. Does this mean, that for example "%le" behaves always like "%e"?
I tried hard to find an example where I get a difference between the "%le"-output and the "%e"-output … without any success. Can it be, that "%le" and "%e" produce generally the same output in the printf-context? I am using the Visual Studio Version 16.11.5 with the MSC-Version 19.29.30136 (MSC_FULL_VER is “192930136“). Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

//to get the MSC-compiler version
#define XSTR(x) STR(x)
#define STR(x) #x
#pragma message("_MSC_FULL_VER:")
#pragma message(XSTR(_MSC_FULL_VER))

int main()
{
    double d = 1.123456789123456789123456789;
    long double ld = static_cast<long double>(d);

    printf("%.20e\n" , d);
    printf("%.20le\n", d);
    printf("%.20le\n", ld);
    printf("%.20e\n" , ld);

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the corresponding output:

```
1.12345678912345681155e+00
1.12345678912345681155e+00
1.12345678912345681155e+00
1.12345678912345681155e+00
```

Comment: It has no effect because of default argument promotions. `float` is promoted to `double` when calling a variadic function.

Comment: It's needed for `scanf()`, though, because it uses pointers to the actual variable, and there's no promotion.

Comment: As Barmar said, the `l` it has no effect if you're talking about `float` versus `double`. It's allowed so that it's consistent with `scanf`, where there *is* a difference between `%f` and `%lf`. As for `double` versus `long double`, I think you have undefined behavior, and you're just getting lucky. On many systems `long double` is the same as `double`. You can check by printing the `sizeof(long double)`. The correct specifier for `long double` is `%Lf`.

Comment: I guess you're just trying to have fun with the "(good) old printf", but honestly, I think it just adds confusion. If you're asking about `printf`, just say that -- the adjectives aren't going to help you get better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2018 C standard says in clause 7.21.6.1, paragraph 7, for `l`:

> … has no effect on a following `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g`, or `G` conversion specifier.

(Text elided to the “…” used above specifies the effects of `l` on other specifiers.)

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out by Eric Postpischil, the length specifier `l` has no effect for the specifiers `f F e E g G a A`. Use the length specifier `L` for printing `long double`.

Note that some compilers (e.g. MSVC) will treat `long double` as if it is `double`.

The following code will generate different output if the compiler supports higher precession for `long double`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double d = 1.123456789123456789123456789;
    long double ld = 1.123456789123456789123456789L;

    printf("Double:      %.20e\n", d);
    printf("Long Double: %.20Le\n", ld);

    printf("Size of double:      %lu\n", sizeof(double));
    printf("Size of long double: %lu\n", sizeof(long double));

}
```

Output with clang 13.0.0 is the following:

```
Double:      1.12345678912345681155e+00
Long Double: 1.12345678912345678911e+00
Size of double:      8
Size of long double: 16
```

Comment: Thanks for charing your insights ... here is a link to the online version of your code : https://godbolt.org/z/sxPhjvxeh